# redux-api-middleware RSA SUCCESS action meta property lost

Tags: redux, react-redux, redux-api-middleware

I'm using the redux-api-middleware.

I have set the meta property of the SUCCESS action and it's being lost when accessing the action in the reducer, regardless of whether I set it as a plain JS object or a function(action, state, res). What makes this strange is that the REQUEST action retains the meta property. It leads me to believe the SUCCESS action is being recreated/overwritten by the middleware and dropping everything except the type and payload properties. The documentation however indicates that the meta property can be used on the SUCCESS action.

Any clues as to what I'm doing wrong or is it a bug?

Comment: Let me rephrase: the SUCCESS RSA output by the middleware does not retain the meta property, whereas the REQUEST RSA output does!

Comment: Turns out I was doing something wrong as it's working now. Just wish I knew what it was!